# Validate partial Modal using Spring @Valid annotation

Tags: validation, spring-mvc

I have a User Modal

```
public class RegisterUser {

    @Size(min = 2, max = 30)
    private String fname;

    @Size(min = 2, max = 30)
    private String lname;

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 6, max = 15)
    private String password;

    ....

    @NotEmpty
    private String publicProfile;

     ... getters and setters

}
```

1) I want to use this modal during registration action (fname, lname, password etc but without publicProfile field)

2) I want to use this modal during myprofile action (all fields except password)

My action for register:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String submitRegisterForm(
        @Valid RegisterUser registerUser,
        BindingResult result,
        Model m) {
    ....
  }
```

Here I don't intend to provide 'publicprofile' on jsp and therefore do not want to validate this field although my Modal has @NotEmpty annotation

My action for myprofile

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myprofile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String submitMyprofileForm(
    @Valid RegisterUser registerUser,
        BindingResult result,
        Model m) {
    ....
}
```

Here I don't intend to provide 'password' field on jsp and therefore do not want to validate this field although my Modal has @NotEmpty and  @Size(min = 6, max = 15) annotation

My question is how can I achieve this ? 
Is there any way where I can say in this modal for this action validate only mentioned fields?

Thanks in advance
Manisha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Validation Groups](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/reference/en-US/html/chapter-groups.html) (for different scenarios) and Spring's [@Validated](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/annotation/Validated.html) annotation to specify which group you want to use

Comment: Thanks a lot.. this is exactly what I was looking for. Accepted your answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is possible with Bean Validation, but you can set up different implementations of [Spring's Validation Interface](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#validator) for different request parameters.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String submitRegisterForm(@Valid RegisterUser registerUser, ...
```

and

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String submitMyprofileForm(@Valid RegisterUser registerUserProfile, ...
```

And then you can use `@InitBinder` to connect different Validators to your request params. You would add these methods to your controller. Just omit the validation you dont want in the second Validator.

```
@InitBinder("registerUser")
protected void initUserBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(new RegisterUserValidator());
}

@InitBinder("registerUserProfile")
protected void initUserBinderProfile(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(new RegisterUserProfileValidator());
}
```

Then you would need to do the annotation stuff manually. You could also use inheritance for your Validators, because they are exactly the same, except the one additional field validation for registration forms.

```
public class RegisterUserValidator implements Validator {
    public boolean supports(Class clazz) {
        return RegisterUser.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    public void validate(Object obj, Errors e) {
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(e, "publicProfile", "empty");
        RegisterUser r = (RegisterUser) obj;
        if (r.getFname().length() < 2) {
            e.rejectValue("fname", "min");
        } else if (r.getFname().length() > 30) {
            e.rejectValue("fname", "max");
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```