# java - spring bean validation - disable specific validation on some fields

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc

I have a view model in my spring mvc application and I need to **enable or disable specific validation on some fields**. For example, suppose I have a 2 view forms that sends data to different controller methods, but both methods use same view model class, something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/method1", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ViewModel method1(@RequestBody @Valid ViewModel viewModel){
      ...
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/method2", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ViewModel method2(@RequestBody @Valid ViewModel viewModel){
    ...
}
```

And this is part of my view model:

```
private Integer test;
```

I need to use `@NotNull` annotation on `test` field, but just in `method2` in controller. In fact, I don't need this validation in `method1`. Is there any way for doing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validate partial Modal using Spring @Valid annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26804468/validate-partial-modal-using-spring-valid-annotation)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35704351/spring-rest-controller-how-to-selectively-switch-off-validation

Answer (score -1):

I think your approach should be to write a super class like

```
class ViewModel {
   @NotNull
   private Integer test;

   public Integer getTest() {
   }
}

class ViewModelSuper extends ViewModel {
   private Integer test;

   @Override
   public Integer getTest() {
   }
}


the you'll have 

@RequestMapping(value = "/method1", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ViewModel method1(@RequestBody @Valid ViewModelSuper viewModel){
  ...
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/method2", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ViewModel method2(@RequestBody @Valid ViewModel viewModel){
...
}
```

Since you only need validation for method2, the super class is used for method1

Answer (score -2):

Remove `@valid` in method1. It will not validate.